# PHP file upload

Tags: php

Hey guys I'm trying to make a file uploader on my website and I have followed a tutorial but it doesn't seem to work. I am currently using the following code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('../../config/config.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = "$" . $_POST['price'];
$photo = $_POST['file'];
$description = nl2br($_POST['description']);

$file_ext = getExt($photo);

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }

} else {

header("Location: ../../index.php");

}


?>
```

I seems to create the temporary file fine but I am not sure why I won't move it. Right now I am testing the code with image files.

Also here is my form code:

```
                <form method="post" action="actions/add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    </br>
                    Listing name: <input type="text" name="name" /></br></br>
                    Listing Photo: <input type="file" name="file"/></br></br>
                    Price: $<input type="text" name="price"/></br></br>
                    Information:</br>
                    <textarea class="add" name="description"></textarea>

                    </br></br>

                    <input class="add" type="submit" name="submit"/>
                </form>
```

EDIT:

Some errors:

```
    Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/Corgi 004.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/stationr/public_html/admin/actions/add.php on line 42

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/chroot/tmp/phpLXObbt' to 'upload/Corgi 004.jpg' in /home/stationr/public_html/admin/actions/add.php on line 42
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do any of the gazillion other questions on this site regarding uploading a file and PHP help? See all those links on the right side?

Comment: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Enable error reporting, check directory permissions, etc. Too localilized.

Comment: Ok i did that and got 2 errors. I have added them to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = "$" . $_POST['price'];
//$photo = $_POST['file'];
$description = nl2br($_POST['description']);

//$file_ext = getExt($photo);

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

$newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;

if (file_exists($newname))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$newname);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
```